# Java Socket block ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, serialization

In Java Object Serialization, you need to create the `ObjectOutputStream` before `ObjectInputStream` in both server and client side, which I did, but the client will run until it gets to the point of having to wait for data from the server (print the message "Done 3" then wait), and on the server side, the code only runs until it gets to the point of reading the first thing from the client (print "Done 1" then wait).
What else I need to do, beside creating the `ObjectOutputStream` before `ObjectInputStream`? From all the searches I've seen, they all mention the order of object creation, and in one case, they said to flush the output right after it is created (like in Example1), but that didn't work either.

Example1

```
ObjectOutputStream dataOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dataOut.flush();
ObjectInputStream dataIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Server

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4554);
        serverRunning = true;
        while (serverRunning) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            ObjectOutputStream dataOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream dataIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Done 1");

            String string = dataIn.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Done 2");

            int number = dataIn.readInt();
            System.out.println("Done 3");

            dataOut.writeUTF("String from server");
            System.out.println("Done 4");

            dataOut.writeInt(1);
            System.out.println("Done 5");

            System.out.println(string + " | " + number);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4554);
    ObjectOutputStream dataOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream dataIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("Done 1");

    dataOut.writeUTF("String from client");
    System.out.println("Done 2");

    dataOut.writeInt(2);
    System.out.println("Done 3");

    String string = dataIn.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Done 4");

    int number = dataIn.readInt();
    System.out.println("Done 5");

    socket.close();
    System.out.println(string + " | " + number);
```

//Edit:
So, if I change every `writeUTF()` `writeInt()` to `writeObject()`, also change every `readUTF()` `readInt()` to `readObject()` (adding the corresponding cast for `String` and `int`) the problem goes away, on Server and Client side. But I don't get it why this would be the case, is there an explanation for this behavior and a fix? I would use `DataOuput/InputStream`, but I need to send/get objects too, so `DataOuput/InputStream` won't help me.

Comment: it't unmeaningful to flush after creation the stream. flush after each write. anyway, this is only a remind. you may debug other things.

Comment: Why are you using serialization when you are only using `writeUTF/Int()` and `readUTF/Int()`? You could use `DataInput/OutputStream` and avoid all these complications. And what does Example1 have to do with your actual code? @exudong You should not flush after every write, and if there is a buffered stream under the `ObjectOutputStream` you do need to flush it after creation if you're then going to create an `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: @exudong Yeah, I thought it was weird too that suggestion about the flush right after creation, but it doesn't hurt to mention, if only to just filter answers about that, what else do you mean to debug, by that comment I take it that you've seen what is wrong?

Comment: @user207421 this was just a simple example, but later on, I will need objects too, not just String and Integers only.  Example1 was added to show how that person said to do, flush after creation, which I though was weird too.

Comment: It isn't weird if you have a buffered stream under the `ObjectOutputStream`, as you often do for performance reasons. In that circumstance it is essential. What you need to do is flush before switching from writing to reading, at both ends.

Comment: @sValentin, because there's no obvious error message, so I think it needs to debug it . e.g. use tcpdump or wireshark to observe if there's really data transfered on network.